# How do I evaluate boolean expression with many arguments?

Tags: java

I am trying to set up a condition check for my code. However, the code has become long and complex. I need a simpler version of the code that can easily do the job.

I have tried to compare three boolean values separated by brackets such that I only compare two values.

```
if (
    (((userState[0][0]&&userState[0][1])&&(userState[0][2]))) || 
    (((userState[1][0]&&userState[1][1])&&(userState[1][2]))) ||
    (((userState[2][0]&&userState[2][1])&&(userState[2][2]))) ||
    (((userState[0][0]&&userState[1][0])&&(userState[2][0]))) ||
    (((userState[0][1]&&userState[2][1])&&(userState[1][1]))) ||
    (((userState[0][2]&&userState[2][2])&&(userState[1][2]))) ||
    (((userState[0][0]&&userState[2][2])&&(userState[1][1]))) ||
    (((userState[1][2]&&userState[1][1])&&(userState[2][0])))
)
```

Comment: You could remove all the unnecessary parentheses.

Comment: This is more of a question for [codereview.se], but you can use `for` loops to check the individual combinations.

Comment: what are you actually checking for? seems like there is every possible combination.

so you check if there are 3 values true in the array?

Comment: @BlakkM9 No. It is a boolean two-dimensional array. I am only checking if the value at that position is true and forms a pattern successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use nested loop:

```
boolean result;
for (int i = 0; i < userState.length; i++) {
 for (int j = 0; j < userState[i].length; j++) {
  result |= userStage[i][j];
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will archive the same results. But if it does you can set result to false in the beginning and in the loop ``if (userStage[i][j]) {result=true;break;}``

Answer (score 1):

Clean code suggests to never write such code in the first place.

If at all, you could for example create small helper methods for each line, like:

```
private hasStateConditionXyz(boolean[][] userState) {
  return userState[0][0]&&userState[0][1])&&(userState[0][2];
}
```

where "Xyz" would be a nice handsome name that tells the reader what the *intention* of that check is.

Of course, that breaks your ability to somehow *loop* over your array.

In other words:

- if possible, see if it is possible to compute your result by looping over that array, instead of writing down such manual "patterns"
- if not, consider using such named helper methods

Where, in the end, the real answer might be to step back and look at the overall problem to solve. Meaning: when you have such a complex "state machine", then it might be better to really create a state machine. Or to use some sort of "work flow" engine. Such tools allow you to express such complex (business?) rules in much more concise and readable ways.